# Merge multiple rows from one column, separated by nonblank row data in other column

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a table that is like this, which is quite messy because of all the unnecessary blank cells.  I have already removed rows that were completely blank, but now I am on this part. Forgive me for being new to this process.  I have searched, but most of my results involve buying tools.

That being said, I am open to the use of Excel, Access or SQL (SSMS) if any of these are capable of accomplishing the below task.

Please provide thorough guidance if your solution uses Excel, Access, or VBA.

```
Row   Unique ID                         Text
__________________________________________________________________
1     555                               The Quick Brown
2                                       Fox Jumped
3                                       Over The Lazy Dog
4     321                               Doe Re Me
5                                       Fa So La
6                                       Ti Doe
```

The final product that I want to try to get would look like this (note the row #'s).  That being said, I am not overly concerned with having the line breaks in each text box, it could all be one one row if there's no other way:

```
Row   Unique ID                         Text
__________________________________________________________________
1     555                               The Quick Brown
                                        Fox Jumped
                                        Over The Lazy Dog
2     321                               Doe Re Me
                                        Fa So La
                                        Ti Doe
```

I am essentially wanting the "text" rows to be merged for the unique ID, then when it recognizes a new unique ID, it will merge the corresponding text cells, and so on.

Comment: Do you want this revised data saved to a table? Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function can concatenate the multiple record text values to a single string (with or without line breaks). Review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html. Run an UPDATE sql action to save to another table. Or could just use report Sorting & Grouping features with a RunningSum textbox in UniqueID group section.

Comment: Correction, run INSERT or MAKE TABLE sql action.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "could just use report Sorting & Grouping features with a RunningSum textbox in UniqueID group section"?

Comment: Suggest you research building reports and RunningSum property. Do you really need the row id?

Comment: No I do not need Row ID.. it was just there for reference in the example

Comment: So you could do a simple report that just lists the records sequentially. If you want to merge the values into one continuous string, that will require VBA code, as shown in the Allen Browne tutorial. Or export to Excel to manipulate as shown in answers. And then reimport? Not my preference.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier solution to this but this is what I could come up with,

Step 1 : Select column A and with help of go to special select all the blank cells and write in formula bar =A2 which should fill all the empty cells with IDs.

[image]

Step 2: In cell C2 write this formula =IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1  & CHAR(10) & B2) and drag as needed.

[image]

Step 3: Write this formula in cell D2 =IF(A2<>A3,1,"") and drag as required.
[image]

Step 4: Filter the values with 1 in column D and apply wrap text.

[image]

Comment: When I click "find and select">Select blanks and click okay, I cannot add (=A2) all of them in the format you describe.  I can only edit one cell at a time, it does not seem to populate all of the blank rows accordingly

Comment: @Mitchell you need to press CTRL+ENTER after putting value in cell A2.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple report in Access.

For the control (TextBox) holding the Row, select Properties, and set *Hide Duplicates* to: Yes.

Comment: This doesn't do anything.

Comment: It sure does. Perhaps you miss an index.

Comment: Miss an index?  What do you mean?  Sorry I'm not familiar with back end Access.  I am very new to it.  Do I need to create an index using a field?

Comment: Go to table design. Select Index in the band.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VBA code for merging the cells based on the values in text column

1.) Add a new column and apply the formula =A1 and drag and drop till row#6

2.) In VBEditor, use the below code in a loop

```
if Range("C" & i).Value = "0" Then
Range("A" & i - 1, "A" & i).Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True end if
```

Comment: When I try to run this code, it gives me the error "invalid outside procedure" and highlights "C" in the first line. Also, the last line is in red.  How to fix?

Comment: Dim i As Integer
i = 1
If Range("L" & i).Value = "0" Then
Range("A" & i - 1, "A" & i).Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
            i = i + 1
    Loop

Answer (score 0):

[Click for excel image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOPTk.png)    @Mitchell
set the column D with formula, =B1, = B2, =B3 ... =B6 and
use the below code in vbe editor.

```
Sub check()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 j = 0
For i = 1 To 6

If Range("D" & i).Value = "0" Then

Range("A" & i - 1, "A" & i).Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

Range("B" & i - 1, "B" & i).Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Else
        j = j + 1
          Range("A" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = j
        End If


Next i


MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```